# How can I get total count of each words in elasticsearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I searched about the question but couldn't find any useful answer. I want to get the total count for each word in a document, for example I have some tweets in my indices and there is a tweet that says something like this “It is so boring here I want to go to my home sweet home”. The query should return the response like this:

```
It:1
is:1
so:1
boring:1
here:1
I:1
want:1
to:2
go:1
my:1
home:2
sweet:1
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: did you look at aggregations?

Comment: i checked them. they doesn't work the way i want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`term vectors`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html), which leverages analyzers. As as it do so, you can define any analyzer you need, i.e. stemming analyzer to transform words to root/normal form.
Take a look at [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) for further details.

In:

```
POST so/_close
PUT so/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis":{ 
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "name": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST so/_open
PUT so/t1/_mapping
{
  "t1": {
    "properties": {
      "tweet": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true,
        "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
POST so/t1/1
{"tweet": "It is so boring here I want to go to my home sweet home. So I'm bored"}
```

Out:

```
{
   "_index": "so",
   "_type": "t1",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "term_vectors": {
      "tweet": {
         "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 13,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_ttf": 17
         },
         "terms": {
            "bore": {
               "term_freq": 2,
               ...
            },
            "go": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "here": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "home": {
               "term_freq": 2,
               ...
            },
            "i": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "i'm": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "is": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "it": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "my": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "so": {
               "term_freq": 2,
               ...
            },
            "sweet": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            },
            "to": {
               "term_freq": 2,
               ...
            },
            "want": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               ...
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried the query, it worked but when i add appendices to the words in the indexes it counts the words with appendices as a whole new word. Is there any way to fix it? for example: boring&bored should be count as same word.

Comment: For PUT so/t1/_mapping on my ES index get this error:

Mapping definition for [text] has unsupported parameters:  [index_analyzer : my_analyzer]

It gives me current error. Can't figure out where is a problem
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, at least not without details. Please create question on SO, providing your mapping, community will try to help