# Elastic opposite query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm using elastic search for classic queries LIKE "search all documents with G4 in name and LG in manfucaturer". This is ok. But what if I have a lot of documents and database with lot of search terms and I need to know which documents match some specific multicolumn terms. For example:

Documents:

```
[
    {
     "id": 5787,
     "name": "Smartphone G4",
     "manufacturer": "LG",
     "description": "The revolutionary LG G4 design can only be described as forward thinking—with a classic touch."
    },
    {
     "id": 68779,
     "name": "Smartphone S6",
     "manufacturer": "Samsung",
     "description": "The Samsung Galaxy S6 is powerful to use and beautiful to behold."
    }
]
```

...

Terms:

```
[
   {
     "id": "587",
     "name": "G4",
     "manufacturer": "LG",
     "description": "classic touch"
    },
    {
     "id": "364",
     "manufacturer": "Samsung",
     "description": "galaxy s6"
    }
]
```

...

Result:

```
{
  "587": [5787],
  "364": [68779]
}
```

OR:

```
{
  "5787": [587],
  "68779": [364]
}
```

I need list of documents and list of terms which corresponds them (or oposite). In small amount of terms, it should be possible to apply all rules one by one and save matching documents. But I have milions of documents and thousands of terms. So, it is not possible to aply them one by one. Is it possible in another way?

Comment: Hey buddy, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913808/how-can-i-get-total-count-of-each-words-in-elasticsearch-document

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I need to compare many documents with many search terms. On linked question, there is only word counter. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html is exactly what I wanted. It can store your queries and execute them against documents.