# Getting Multi-Term Phrase Frequencies Per Document in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913808/how-can-i-get-total-count-of-each-words-in-elasticsearch-document) in elastic search, but given a set of multiple term phrases. It seems that example only works for single term queries. For example, if I have a document like this:

```
PUT /test
{
    "text": "a b a b a"
}
```

I want to be able to search like this:

```
GET /test/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase": {
            "text": "a b"
        }
    }
}
```

And I want it to return all documents with the phrase "a b", and the frequency of this particular match. So for the above document, it would be 2.

Comment: It will only work if your `a b` phrase is an actual term in your index. If you text `a b a b a` is analyzed into `a` and `b` terms then what you want won't work.

Comment: The implementation of match_phrase has to count the matches right? It's just that we're not seeing it. I mean, how else would match_phrase work?

Comment: You can see the matches with highlighters, but that's it.

Comment: The highlighters work by adding style tags to each term. Surely then, it can count how many times it highlights stuff right? Not trying to troll. Just trying to understand.