# Text similarity in elasticsearch while using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

For example, I have these documents:

1 - "hello world, hey there"

2 - "hello world"

3 - "my account code is 1234"

4 - "my account code is 2378"

So, I want to get the most popular texts, ideally with counts:

"hello world": 2, 
"my account code is": 2.

Is this possible with elasticsearch?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31914848/5330655

Comment: in the provided link, it is returning the similarity and occurrence of one sentence, meanwhile my question is to find the similarity between multiple documents that already exists in ES